# SonarLint Eclipse plugin does not find any issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarlint

I would like to use **SonarLint** to find possible issues in my Java code. I installed SonarLint plugin from the official Eclipse Marketplace successfully. **According to the console logs it runs, and analyzes the files, but cannot find any issue.**

I checked the rules in *Windows -> Preferences -> SonarLint -> Rules Configuration -> Java*, and they are set properly.

I copy pasted a BAD example from the rules (to make sure it is not compliant), saved my java file, but nothing. SonarLint said it found 0 issue as you can see on the picture below:

[image]

What do I miss? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Version of my Eclipse: 2021-06 (4.20.0)

Version of SonarLint: 7.1

Comment: Is the Java file processed? Your cropped screenshot also hides whether you put the Java file in a source folder and which Java version you are using. And why are you using an outdated Eclipse?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I realized SonarLint works for some files in the project for example: Project/src/main/java/com/company/lib/graph/shared/distributors/arcs/AlternateArcAdmin.java
BUT does not work for /subProject/src/main/java/com/company/lib/graph/server/export/converter/ppt/SVGConnectorDataExtractor.java

I use Java 11 to build the project

Comment: How did you deduce this?